# df.fillna(df.mean()) does not work as expected

Tags: python, pandas

i don't understand why this one is not working:

```
df = pd.read_csv("EXAMPLE_2.csv",sep=';')
df.head()
```

[image]
then i use:

```
df=df.fillna(df.mean())
```

I would expect to have the yellow NaN values replaced with the mean of the column but I get exactly the same output as before?

Thank you, R

Comment: I think there are strings, columns, what is `print (df.dtypes)` ?

Comment: Zeitkanal_Sec                              float64 ;
Zeitkanal_Min                               object

Comment: And all columns should be numeric?

Comment: yes excatly @jezrael

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If all columns should be numeric, use [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) with [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html) for convert to numeric, also parameter `errors='coerce'` replace not parseable values to `NaN`s:

```
df = df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')
#alternative
#df = df.apply(lambda x: pd.to_numeric(x, errors='coerce'))

df = df.fillna(df.mean())
```

Comment: Nice one, jezrael!  Nice one!!